# Filling specific duplicated values within the rows of a dataframe with NAs

Tags: r, duplicates

For each row of my dataframe, I am currently trying to select all the duplicated values equal to 4 in order to set them "equal" to NA.

My dataframe is like this:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "

   1  1  1  2  2  4  4  4  
   1  2  1  1  4  4  4  4", 

header=FALSE)
```

What I need to obtain is:

```
   1  1  1  2  2  4   NA  NA
   1  2  1  1  4  NA  NA  NA
```

I have found information on how to eliminate duplicated rows or columns, but I really do not know how to proceed here.. many thanks for any help

Comment: To be precise- you want to remove all of the `4`s *except* the first one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes you will want to avoid `apply` because it destroys the multi-class feature of dataframe objects. This is a `by` approach:

```
> do.call(rbind, by(dat, rownames(dat), 
        function(line) {line[ duplicated(unlist(line)) & line==4 ] <- NA; line} ) )
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  1  1  2  2  4 NA NA
2  1  2  1  1  4 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 3):

`which` and `apply` are helpful here.

```
> dat <- t(apply(dat, 1, function(X) {X[which(X==4)][-1] <- NA ; X})) 
> dat
[1,]  1  1  1  2  2  4 NA NA
[2,]  1  2  1  1  4 NA NA NA
```

But there's probably a way around having to use the transpose (`t`) function here, can anyone help me out?

Comment: That's just how apply works and is documented to do. It's strange to me too.

Answer (score 3):

`duplicated` can be used in this way with an `apply`:

```
dat <- t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {x[duplicated(x) & x == 4] <- NA ; x}))
```